# Building a Pandas dataframe using multiprocessing leads to errors

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to build a big dataframe using a function that takes some arguments and return partial dataframes. I have a long list of documents to parse and extract relevant information that will go the big dataframe, and I am trying to do it using `multiprocessing.Pool` to make the process go faster.

My code looks like this :

```
    from multiprocessing import *
    from settings import *
    
    server_url = settings.SERVER_URL_UAT
    username =   settings.USERNAME
    password =   settings.PASSWORD
    
    def wrapped_visit_detail(args): 
        
        global server_url
        global username
        global password
        
        # visit_detail return a dataframe after consuming args
    
        return visit_detail(server_url, args, username, password) 
    
    # Trying to pass a list of arguments to wapped_visit_detail
    
    visits_url = [doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    df = pd.concat( [ df,
                      pool.map( wrapped_visit_detail,
                                visits_url
                                )
                      ],
                    ignore_index = True
                    )
```

When I run this, I got this error

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7f2c88a43208>'. Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle _thread._local objects",)'
```

**EDIT**

To illustrate my problem I created this simple figure

[image]

This is painfully slow and not scalable at all

And I am looking to make the code not serial but rather as parallelized as possible

[image]

Thank you all for your great comments so far, yes, **I a using shared variable** as parameters to this function that pulls the files and extract the individuals dataframes, it seems ot be my issue indeed

I am suspecting something wrong in the way I call `pool.map()`

Any tip would be really welcome

Comment: Which OS are you using? I was never able to use pool.map() on Windows.

Comment: Hi Ssayan, I am using Ubuntu

Comment: I can't fully reproduce as I don't have what you import but `pool.map() ` returns a list so I would suggest you do this  `df = pd.concat(pool.map(wrapped_visit_detail, visits_url), ignore_index=True)`. When I use what you did I get an error but not the same so I don't think that would solve fully your issue. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708455/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-local-objects-when-using-dask-on-pandas-datafra) your error may come from the use of global variables.

Comment: I also use `multithreading` in the context of processing `pandas.DataFrame` and never got an error like this. Your error (about pickeling) indicates that the data transfered between to processes is not pickable. See https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html to find out which data types are pickable). Maybe there is more then just a `DataFrame`? Or the cells in the `DF` containes unpickable types.

Answer (score 3):

You may have realised on your own, that there is actually no "sharing" possible, among Python-interpreter and its sub-processes. No sharing, only absolutely independent and "disconnected" replicas of the `__main__`'s original, (in Windows a complete, top-down) state-full copy of the Python-interpreter, with all its internal variables, modules and whatsoever. Any change of there copies is not propagated back into the `__main__` or elsewhere. Once more, if you try to compose *"Big dataframe"* from `~ +100k` individually pre-produced *"partial dataframes"*, you will get an awfully if not unacceptably low performance.

Losing advantages from partial-producers' latency-masking plus headbanging into the RAM-allocation costs and potentially even a need to turn memory-I/O many times worse, falling into a trap of 10,000x slower physical/virtual-memory swapping, as in-RAM capacities ceased to be able to hold all data - as might happen upon ex-post attempt to
`pd.concat( _a_HUGE_in_RAM_store_first_LIST_of_ALL_100k_plus_partial_DFs_, ... )`
which is <sub>*(*unless you test Stack Overflow sponsors of Knowledge sense of humour and patience of others*)*</sub>
a no go ANTI-pattern.

---

> **Q :**
> <sub>*"  Any tip ... "*</sub>

**A :**
No matter how simple this one is, here, due to Python-interpreted, process-to-process communication constraints

> *<sub>( unhandled EXC reporter says) :</sub>*
>
> ```
> multiprocessing.
>            pool.MaybeEncodingError:
>
> Error sending result:
> '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7f2c88a43208>'.
>
> Reason:
> 'TypeError("can't pickle _thread._local objects",)'
> ```

So,
here we are. Python-interpreter has to use "pickle"-like SER/DES whenever it tries to send/receive as single bit of data from one process ( typ. the `__main__` upon sending launch parameters, or worker-processes upon sending their remote results' objects back to the `__main__` ) to another.

That's fine, whenever the SER/DES-serialisation is possible ( here not being the case )

### Options :

- Best avoid any and all object-passing ( objects are prone to SER/DES-failures )
- If obsessed with passing them, try some more capable SER/DES-encoder, replacing a default `pickle` with `import dill as pickle` has saved me many times ( yet not in every case, see above )
- Design better problem-solving strategy, that does not rely on ill-assumed "shared"-use of Pandas dataframe amongst more (fully independent) sub-processes, that cannot and do not access "the same" dataframe, but theirs locally-isolated replica thereof (re-read more about sub-process independence and memory-space separation)

Nota bene:
School-book SLOC-s are nice in school-book sized examples, yet are awfully expensive performance ANTI-patterns in real-world use cases, the more in production-grade code-execution.

Tip:
If performance is **The Target**,
produce independent file-based results and join them afterwards. *"Big dataframe"* composition from *"partial dataframes"* represent a mix of sins, that cause you many performance ANTI-pattern problems, the failure to SER/DES-`pickle` being just a one, a small one (visible to naked eye)

Decisions ( & the costs associated with making them ) are in all cases on you.

You might like some further reads on [how to boost performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337080).

Comment: I'm the author of `dill`.  With regard to your second "option": I'd suggest trying `multiprocess`, a fork of `multiprocessing` that uses `dill`, and can utilize `dill.settings` for serialization variants.

Comment: Sure,I know @MikeMcKerns,we've already discussed `dill`-related issues here already in past & I keep recommending `dill` for using as a smart SER/DES replacement IIRC since ~2008 (the time is so fast...). Here, the O/P problem is to re-factor the overall strategy of processing, if performance boost is to get achieved (doable). A move from `multiprocessing` to `multiprocess` or `joblib` does not help for achieving a reasonable End-2-End processing performance (HPC-grade processing speeds being far, indeed far ahead. The O/P struggles instead with a 1st visible show-stopper, RAM-swaps are next )

Comment: Yeah, I just mentioned it more due to the fact the OP is attempting to use `multiprocessing` and you mentioned object-sharing across processes.  Were it me, and I had an array (or `pandas.Series`) to share, I might instead use a shared memory array from `multiprocess` -- which can be quite fast.  You have to use `Process` and `Lock`  objects and the like, but it's worth it.  I'm sure it's been done with a `pandas.DataFrame`, but I've never tried it (though I've used a 2D `numpy` array).  There's also the alternative of using a `map`  (or similar) built on top of `mpi4py`. Ship near-zero data.